# How to sign a PSBT with BitcoinerLAB?

Tags: javascript, bip174-psbt, miniscript

First of all, We are using [bitcoinerLab](https://github.com/orgs/bitcoinerlab/repositories).

[image: Example]

From the seed, we generate the Master Key, and with the path, we create the child key 0 (the parent's) and child key 1 (the child's). Now, from these keys, we obtain the Grandchild keys with which we will generate infinite addresses containing the following policy:

```
or(pk(@dadKey),and(pk(@sonKey),after(20)))
```

What we want is that through a Grandchild address, which will have funds locked by the previous policy, we need either the parent or the child to try to create a transaction and unlock these funds.

In the descriptor that I create, I pass the GrandChildKey's public key.

```
var publickeydad=masterNode.derivePath(`m${ORIGIN_PATH}${KEY_PATH}/0`).publicKey;

    const wshDescriptor = new Descriptor({
        expression: wshExpression,
        network,
        signersPubKeys: [publickeydad] 
    });
```

Now, the issue arises when signing the PSBT. We want to sign it with ChildKey 0, which will correspond to 'dadKey' in our policy. The error occurs right here in the 'masterNode' attribute. How should we sign it?

```
descriptors.signers.signBIP32({ psbt, masterNode: descriptors.keyExpressionBIP32({
        masterNode: masterNode,
        originPath: ORIGIN_PATH,
        keyPath: `${KEY_PATH}`
    })});
```

In summary, we want to generate infinite GrandChild addresses with the previously described policy, and we want to sign transactions either with ChildKey0 or ChildKey1 to unlock the funds in the GrandChild addresses:

The full code:

```
import * as bitcoin from "bitcoinjs-lib";
import { Psbt, networks } from 'bitcoinjs-lib';
import * as ecpair from "ecpair";
import * as secp from "tiny-secp256k1";
const ECPair = ecpair.ECPairFactory(secp);
import * as fs from 'fs';
import * as secp256k1 from '@bitcoinerlab/secp256k1';
import * as descriptors from '@bitcoinerlab/descriptors';
import { compilePolicy } from '@bitcoinerlab/miniscript';
import { generateMnemonic, mnemonicToSeedSync } from 'bip39';
import { encode as afterEncode } from 'bip65';

const ORIGIN_PATH = `/69420'/1'/0'`; 
const KEY_PATH = `/0/0`; 
const network = networks.testnet;
const { Descriptor, BIP32, ECPair2 } = descriptors.DescriptorsFactory(secp256k1);
var policy =`or(pk(@dadKey),and(pk(@sonKey),after(20)))`;


async function send_tx(){
    const toAddress='mqCMd6LtWXLqKgCiPyVzzhKQvb1AKixgtu'
    const network = networks.testnet;
    const EXPLORER = 'https://blockstream.info/testnet';

    const masterNode = BIP32.fromSeed(mnemonicToSeedSync('uncle industry hospital amused when paper timber exact accuse exotic squeeze vote'),network); 
    const wshAddress='tb1q8rnzmm5ttrl8fc94y94vpyzf62e69cq85v7dwvve33h3ta85xlpqe7wdhl'
    const utxo = await (
    await fetch(`${EXPLORER}/api/address/${wshAddress}/utxo`)
    ).json();

    if (utxo?.[0]) {
        const txHex = await (
        await fetch(`${EXPLORER}/api/tx/${utxo?.[0].txid}/hex`)
    ).text();
    const inputValue = utxo[0].value;
    const psbt = new Psbt({ network });
    
    const wshExpression = "wsh(andor(pk([57836ab7/69420'/1'/0']tpubDDLpvA16cXnaKBY4r8sy7fmZV5ATP9a2ik7kycRKn3twfEFngNGPk8u2CYfR2yrLqLJFdHjh2Pm3YWHTFoepVaFeewHaqoSmFUbxbbLzhfa/0/1/0),after(20),pk([57836ab7/69420'/1'/0']tpubDDLpvA16cXnaKBY4r8sy7fmZV5ATP9a2ik7kycRKn3twfEFngNGPk8u2CYfR2yrLqLJFdHjh2Pm3YWHTFoepVaFeewHaqoSmFUbxbbLzhfa/0/0/0)))"

    // La clave publica del GRANDchild del padre
    var publickeydad=masterNode.derivePath(`m${ORIGIN_PATH}${KEY_PATH}/0`).publicKey;

    const wshDescriptor = new Descriptor({
        expression: wshExpression,
        network,
        signersPubKeys: [publickeydad] 
    });
    
    wshDescriptor.updatePsbt({ psbt, txHex, vout: utxo[0].vout });
   
    psbt.addOutput({
        address: toAddress,
        value: inputValue - 1000
    });

    descriptors.signers.signBIP32({ psbt, masterNode: descriptors.keyExpressionBIP32({
        masterNode: masterNode,
        originPath: ORIGIN_PATH,
        keyPath: `${KEY_PATH}`
    })});
    

    wshDescriptor.finalizePsbtInput({ index: 0, psbt });
    const spendTx = psbt.extractTransaction();
    const spendTxPushResult = await (
        await fetch(`${EXPLORER}/api/tx`, {
        method: 'POST',
        body: spendTx.toHex()
        })
    ).text();
    console.log(`Pushing: ${spendTx.toHex()}`);
    console.log(`Tx pushed with result: ${spendTxPushResult}`);

    }


}


send_tx()
```